# How to create same route name for differents subdomains in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I'm actually using **[nwidart/laravel-modules](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules)** on Laravel 5.8 and I got problem with some routes.

I created some modules (module_1, module_2, module_3).

Each module has file web.php, and in these files, I added these lines:

*module_1 web.php*:

```
Route::domain('module1.domain.com')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', 'ModuleOneController@index')->name('home');
});
```

*module_2 web.php*:

```
Route::domain('module2.domain.com')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', 'ModuleTwoController@index')->name('home');
});
```

*module_3 web.php*:

```
Route::domain('module3.domain.com')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', 'ModuleThreeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

And in my main web.php in laravel project:

```
Route::domain('domain.com')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

I can access to these urls and each controllers are called on each subdomains, but when I want to call the function `route('home')`, it always returns https://module3.domain.com event if I specified each route names in different domain.

I would to get:

`route('home')` => `'https://module1.domain.com'` when I call it in `module1.domain.com`

`route('home')` => `'https://module2.domain.com'` when I call it in `module2.domain.com`
etc...

> **Is there a way to call the same route name in different domain and get**
>   **differents results ?**

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'module.domain.com'], function (){
    Route::post('login', [
        'as' => 'login',
        'uses' => 'AuthController@login'
    ]);
    // ... all route
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'module1.domain.com'], function (){        
    // ... all route
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never used the package "nwidart/laravel-modules". However, typically laravel uses the `APP_URL` variable available in your `.env` file to actually match the domain in routes. Maybe it's defined as "https://module3.domain.com" in your .env file and that is why its matching that route only.

Maybe there is a way to define multiple APP_URLs using the "nwidart/laravel-modules" package?

This is not a solution but it might lead you in the right direction. Otherwise, someone will have to study the package details in order to actually understand the issue.

Comment: All my subdomains have the same `.env` file, I found temp solution with condition on `if(Request::server("SERVER_NAME") == "module1.domain.com"){ my_routes_heres.... }`

Comment: sort of workaround yes, try using different APP_URL for different subdomains then, that might work?